# How do I use classes from an imported library in netbeans (java)

Tags: java, netbeans

This must be the simplest thing. I have been trying to do this for hours. I know how to import libraries into netbeans but how do I use classes in these libraries using imports? I have been trying unsuccessfully for hours to use the javacv library on 64bit linux and when I try to import the necessary files from the library netbeans tells me the package does not exist. I want to access a java file `example.java` inside `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.linux-x86_64` which is inside `opencv-2.4.8-linux-x86_64.jar`. How do I actually import this so I can do the following: `example obj = new example`?

Also, in almost every reference to javacv I see this `import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;` but nowhere have I actually seen this in any of the files readily available by google. What's the deal?

Comment: Normally you would just use: import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.linux-x86_64.example or import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.linux-x86_64.* provided you have imported the jar file into your project using netbeans.

Comment: I have tried this but netbeans refuses to accept that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try, I will be as specific as possible:

1. Copy the library folder you want to use
2. Paste it in the "src" folder of your project folder

Once you completed the above two tasks, you can import different classes from the library using the following code:

```
import nameOfLibraryFolder.*;
```

The above code will import all the classes from within the library. Replace "nameOfLibraryFolder" with the name of the library folder, to be more specific, *the folder that contains all the classes of the library*, to be even more specific, *the folder that you placed in your project's subfolder called "src"*.

In order to import a specific class from the library, you need to replace the * symbol with the class name.

For example:

```
import nameOfLibraryFolder.className;
```

but if the class is in a subfolder, then:

```
import nameOfLibraryFolder.subFolderName.className;
```

I hope this is specific enough, and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans, it is rather easy to iomport a external `jar` and utilize it.
First you need to add `jar` file in project tab by right clicking on the `library` node.
Then, in this project, just `import the.name` in your java file.
This should work, I have used Netbeans for three years

Comment: It won't recognize that the library is there.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty have to correctly put this `jar` into your project before actually do the `import` job?

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty what do you mean by `recognize`? is there any warning or error?

Comment: Netbeans tells me the package does not exist.

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty actually method to load a `jar` into netbeans in so easy that almost have no other way to do it. Since netbeans gives this message, I think this possibly because you have not correctly adding your `jar` file, or the `jar` file is corrupted or invalid !

Answer (score 0):

You many need to do one of the following option.

- Add an new Library to NetBeans, then add it to you project

  1. If you `Tools -> Library` a popup will come up.
  2. There you can add a new library. Click on `New Library` and name the new Library.
  3. Import a library from the `ClassPath` tab `Add Jar/Folder`
  4. If you want to can also add the javadoc from the `JavaDoc` tab. You would add the file from the library file you downloaded, called `javadoc`. This will allow for the javadocs to be seen while editing your code.
  5. Also you can add the sources file form the `Sources` tab. Import the file named `sources`
  6. Then click on the `Libraries` folder icon in your project and `Add Library`
- Another option is just add the `.jar`.

  1. Right-click on the `Libraries` folder icon in your project and click `Add Jar`
  2. Locate the `.jar` file and add it.

Comment: I already know how to add the library as stated in the post. I'm wondering how to reference classes/files in said library.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have:
package MyProject;

At the top of your project Java wont recognize it. 
 * It seems to be like some sort of sandboxing affect.
 * To use your classes you have to open the directory you 
 * Saved the project to and Copy/Paste the library to the source file.
 * I also found that simply deleting the named package works as well.
 * But now you're no longer linked to that package. -shrugs-