# Write an Excel in Java with parsed information

Tags: java, excel, jsoup

I have a code where I scrape some information from a webpage (it´s just an example), and I would like to introduce that scraped information in excel at the same time, I mean, inside the "for" conditional, when I scrape an element introduce in excel.

Every time I try to implement the code for creating the Excel I have errors. I import POI "jar" files but it keeps not working. Do I have to make it in another class? I don´t really understand in this case how and where the information is saved so that I can "import" all the scraped information to the class where I created the excel worksheet.

The scrapping code is the following:

```
public static final String url = "http://jarroba.com/page/%s/";
public static final int maxPages = 20;  

public static void main (String args[]) {

    for (int i=1; i<maxPages; i++){

        String urlPage = String.format(url, i);
        System.out.println("Comprobando entradas de: "+urlPage);

        // Compruebo si me da un 200 al hacer la petición
        if (getStatusConnectionCode(urlPage) == 200) {

            // Obtengo el HTML de la web en un objeto Document2
            Document document = getHtmlDocument(urlPage);

            // Busco todas las historias de meneame que estan dentro de: 
            Elements entradas = document.select("div.col-md-4.col-xs-12").not("div.col-md-offset-2.col-md-4.col-xs-12");

            // Paseo cada una de las entradas
            for (Element elem : entradas) {
                String titulo = elem.getElementsByClass("tituloPost").text();
                String autor = elem.getElementsByClass("autor").toString();
                String fecha = elem.getElementsByClass("fecha").text();

                System.out.println(titulo+"\n"+autor+"\n"+fecha+"\n");

            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("El Status Code no es OK es: "+getStatusConnectionCode(urlPage));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part show the error?

Comment: The code above is OK, the problem is when I try to introduce the code to create the Excel file and introduce the scrapped information. I don´t know if it is because I have to create the code in a separated class. @vv88

Answer (score 0):

POI is an Apache library used to manipulate many Microsoft Office file types. You don't need to create classes but instead import them into your project to use.

[Apache POI resources](https://poi.apache.org/)

[Importing libraries into Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987577/how-do-i-use-classes-from-an-imported-library-in-netbeans-java)

Comment: But you have to create the structure, and is when I start having problems. Taking codes for other examples it doesn't give me problems. May be the best option is to save all the information in an array and import that array in another class where I create the excel, but I don´t really know how to import that array.

Comment: You can call a public static method from another class that takes an array as its parameter.